# Linq formating DateTime to dd-MM-yyyy in SELECT

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need formartar to select the date in "dd-MM-yyyy", but I'm not getting. Have tested in various ways, but none work. Field formating is: DtFabricacao. I'm using DataTable and want to format the date in Linq prórpio

The Linq is below:

```
public static ResultadoListagemPadrao Grid(string orderna, string ordenaTipo, string filtro, int filtroID = 0)
{
    ERPContext db = new ERPContext();
    var resultado = new ResultadoListagemPadrao();
    var dados = db.ProdutoLote.ToListERP();
    var where = "";
    var id = 0;


    resultado.TotalRegistros = dados.Count();
    resultado.Dados =
        (from a in dados.AsQueryable()
         select new
         {
             a.ProdutoLoteID,
             a.Lote,
             a.Identificacao,                     
             a.DtFabricacao,                     
             a.DtValidade,
             a.QtdeAtual,
             a.QtdeEmUtilizacao
         })
        .Where(where, filtro)
        .OrderBy(orderna + " " + ordenaTipo);
    return resultado;
}
```

Model:

```
public class ProdutoLote : IEntidadeBase
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoLoteID { get; set; }    
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }
    public string Lote { get; set; }
    public string Identificacao { get; set; }
    public string Detalhe { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? DtFabricacao { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DtValidade { get; set; }    
    public decimal QtdeAtual { get; set; }
    public decimal QtdeEmUtilizacao { get; set; }            

    public int EmpresaID { get; set; }
    public string Fixo { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Apagado { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DtApagado { get; set; }
    public int UsuCad { get; set; }
    public DateTime DtCad { get; set; }
    public int UsuAlt { get; set; }
    public DateTime DtAlt { get; set; }
    public int UsuUltAlt { get; set; }
    public DateTime DtUltAlt { get; set; }    
    [ForeignKey("UsuCad")]
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioCad { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UsuAlt")]
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioAlt { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UsuUltAlt")]
    public virtual Usuario UsuarioUltAlt { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmpresaID")]
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }    
    [ForeignKey("ProdutoID")]
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model ERP.Models.Produto

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Html.MontaTitulo("Detalhe produto - " + @Model.ProdutoID.ToString());    
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var oTableSetor;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        GridProdutoLote();     
    });

    function GridProdutoLote() {
        if (oTableSetor===undefined)
        {
            oTableGrid = $('#lista_lote').dataTable({            
                "bServerSide": true,            
                "sAjaxSource": '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ListaGenerica", "Home", new { aController = "ProdutoLote", filtroID = @Model.ProdutoID  } ))', 
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",                   
                "aoColumns": [
                            { "mDataProp": "ProdutoLoteID", "sTitle": "ID"},
                            { "mDataProp": "Lote", "sTitle": "Lote" },
                            { "mDataProp": "Identificacao", "sTitle": "Identificacao"},
                            { "mDataProp": "DtFabricacao", "sTitle": "DtFabricacao"},
                            { "mDataProp": "DtValidade", "sTitle": "DtValidade"},
                            { "mDataProp": "QtdeAtual", "sTitle": "QtdeAtual"},
                            { "mDataProp": "QtdeEmUtilizacao", "sTitle": "QtdeEmUtilizacao"},
                            { "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "fnRender": function (o) {return '<a class="icone_16x16_detalhe" href=/Setor/Detalhar/' + o.aData["ProdutoLoteID"] + '>D</a>';}}                          
                ],
            });

            $('#lista_lote_filter input').unbind();            
            $("#lista_lote").show();
            $("#grid_lote").show();
            $('#lista_lote_filter input').bind('keyup', function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                oTableGrid.fnFilter(this.value);   
            }});  
        }
    };
</script> 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);    
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProdutoID)             
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.Identificacao)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.Descricao)    

    <div class="linha left">  

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Identificacao) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Identificacao)<br />    
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Identificacao, new { style = "width:250px;" })<br />

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Descricao) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descricao)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Descricao, new { style = "width:250px;" })<br />   

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Detalhe) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Detalhe)<br />  
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Detalhe, new { style = "width:250px;" })<br />  


        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.UnidadeMedidaID) * @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.UnidadeMedidaID)<br />   
        @Html.DropDownList("ProdutoBase.UnidadeMedidaID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaUnidadeMedida, String.Empty, new { style = "width:250px;" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.UnidadeMedidaID)<br />

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.Fracao) * @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.Fracao)<br />  
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.Fracao, new { style = "width:250px;" })<br />  

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.QtdeFracao) * @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.QtdeFracao)<br />  
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.QtdeFracao, new { style = "width:250px;" })<br />  

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.UnidadeMedidaIDFracao) * @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.UnidadeMedidaIDFracao)<br />   
        @Html.DropDownList("ProdutoBase.UnidadeMedidaIDFracao", (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaUnidadeMedidaFracao, String.Empty, new { style = "width:250px;" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.UnidadeMedidaIDFracao)<br /> 

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.QtdeMinima) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QtdeMinima)<br />  
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QtdeMinima, new { style = "width:250px;" })<br />  

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.QtdeIdeal) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QtdeIdeal)<br />  
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QtdeIdeal, new { style = "width:250px;" })<br />  

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.QtdeMaxima) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QtdeMaxima)<br />  
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QtdeMaxima, new { style = "width:250px;" })<br />

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.QtdeAtual) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QtdeAtual)<br />  
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QtdeAtual, new { style = "width:250px;", @readonly = "readonly" })<br /><br />  

        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.TemLoteBool, new { @class = "input normal" }) @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.TemLoteBool) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.TemLoteBool)<br />  
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.FracionadoBool, new { @class = "input normal" }) @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.FracionadoBool) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProdutoBase.FracionadoBool)<br />

        <br />
        Campos marcados com *, são do produto base e somente podem ser visualizados e não alterados
        <br /><br />
        @Html.MontaBotoesTelaDetalhar()
        <br /><br />

    </div>    
}

<div class="linha left" id="grid_lote">    
    <div class="linha left separadora" >Dados de lote:</div>
    <br />        
    <br />
    <table id="lista_lote" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>                
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br /><br />
<br /><br />
```

Comment: Is this asp.net MVC? If yes, post the code for your View and your Model. And if not, Where did you try to change the date format? Post that code.

Comment: Do you simply wish to display this info in a Grid control, or are you looking at allowing edits? I'd assume you could just put string format = "dd-MM-yyyy"; before the linq statement and the following in your select new:  DtFabricacao = a.DtFabricacao.toString(format),

Comment: KreepN, I could just put string format. You code, its message error:

Error 2 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type 

Error 3 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Marlon use the @ symbol to send an alert to me when you respond EX: @KreepN 'message goes here'. I didn't see your response til just now when I refreshed. Linq doesn't like the inline code, as it doesn't translate to SQL. Have you considered doing the format in the "get" for the DtFabricacao property?

Comment: @KreepN using get the error is: The specified type member 'DtFabricacaoDesc' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported. Is model:         [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Data Fabricação")]
        public string DtFabricacaoDesc { get { return DtFabricacao != null ? DtFabricacao.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : null; } }

Comment: @marlon.tiedt You should not add the `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` in the Model class, because C# functions are not supported and cannot be converted to equivalebt T-SQL functions while querying the database.

Answer (score 0):

`Error  2 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type` . This is happening because you have done this `.OrderBy(orderna + " " + ordenaTipo);` in `Grid` method, try instead the below code which also formats date

**EDIT**:

```
var queryResult = dados.AsQueryable().Where(where, filtro)
                  .OrderBy(dado => dado.ColumnName1)
                  .ThenBy(dado => dado.ColumnName2).ToList();
resultado.Dados =
    (from a in queryResult 
     select new
     {
         a.ProdutoLoteID,
         a.Lote,
         a.Identificacao,                     
         a.DtFabricacao.HasValue() ? a.DtFabricacao.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : a.DtFabricacao,                     
         a.DtValidade,
         a.QtdeAtual,
         a.QtdeEmUtilizacao
     });
```

Comment: I think you want `ThenBy` instead of the second `OrderBy`, otherwise it will reorder the entire dataset.

Comment: @D Stanley. You are absolutely right, my bad. I am updating my answer, thanks.